# How to create an array of objects of a specific class type

Tags: java

I have a function that returns an Object.  The Object can contain an array of primatives or an array of objects.  In C# I can create an empty array of objects or primatives using code like:

```
Array values = Array.CreateInstance(/*Type*/type, /*int*/length);
```

Is there an equivalent in Java?

Answer (score 1):

> How to create an array of objects of a specific class type

```
Test[] tests = new Test[length] ;
```

And if you want to have a mix up of Primitives and Objects, though it is not suggestable, If you want to mix primitives with Objects

```
Object[] objs = new Object[length];
```

That allows you to both primitives([`in form of wrappers`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class)) and normal Objects together.

If you have a class called Test of your own, you can create an array of Test's like

Note that until you initialise the elements in that array, they have `null` as their value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only know the element type at execution time, I think you're looking for [`Array.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int...-).

```
Object intArray = Array.newInstance(int.class, 10);
Object stringArray = Array.newInstance(String.class, 10);
```

(That will create an `int[]` and a `String[]` respectively.)

Comment: OK that works great.  Thanks.  Now what if I am creating the object type from a class path string.  For example:  Class<?> cls = Class.forName("myclasspath");

Comment: @Mike: So use `Object array = Array.newInstance(cls, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] array = new Object[length];
```

Or with your own type:

```
MyType[] array = new MyType[length];
```